# Hadoop Name Node - No groups available for user anonymous

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I was checking the logs of my Name Node and I found this:

```
2016-06-04 03:09:28,843 INFO  BlockStateChange (BlockManager.java:computeReplicationWorkForBlocks(1527)) - BLOCK* neededReplications = 0, pendingReplications = 0.
2016-06-04 03:09:28,960 WARN  security.UserGroupInformation (UserGroupInformation.java:getGroupNames(1521)) - No groups available for user anonymous
... (x8)
2016-06-04 03:09:29,119 WARN  security.UserGroupInformation (UserGroupInformation.java:getGroupNames(1521)) - No groups available for user anonymous
2016-06-04 03:09:29,945 INFO  hdfs.StateChange (FSNamesystem.java:completeFile(3503)) - DIR* completeFile: /spark-history/.abde470b-daaa-4dc7-9097-35d778fe3a5a is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_1292395454_1
```

At this hour, there were no treatment on the cluster and nobody was working on it. This warning appears randomly in the logs.

After further investigations, there is no user anonymous created and I found nothing about it..

Do you have any ideas where to look at? What's this user "anonymous" ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This warning typically means that your user is not defined/visible within the host OS for all nodes in the Hadoop cluster.  The Hadoop code determines a user's set of group memberships by consulting the underlying OS.  If the user is unknown at the OS layer, then Hadoop sees an empty set of group memberships and logs this warning.

The typical fix is to make sure the user is defined at all nodes in the cluster, such as by running useradd.  For large production clusters, integrating with a centralized LDAP server obviously makes this a lot more manageable.

Alternatively, you could choose to ignore the warning.  If your application is not dependent on group memberships for anything (such as HDFS file permissions granting access to a group), then that might be acceptable for your use case.

You can see the hdfs users in `hdfs-site.xml`

For more details, refer [HDFS permission guide](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsPermissionsGuide.html#Group_Mapping)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Any idea about which user is not defined?